# mcufriend SPI connection

Tags: esp8266, spi, display

Bought a cheap LCD form china (mcufriend, pictured below) and I cant understand which pin is which to use it with the SPI interface (starting to get worried that I can't use it), I've figured out this much:

- LCD_RST; reset pin
- LCD_CS; chip select
- LCD_RS;
- LCD_WR;
- LCD_RD;

Which of those is MOSI, SCK, DC? Trying to use it with a ESP8266 (ESP-12).

[image: mcufriend 3.5" TFT screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use that TFT screen with SPI. The SPI interface (`SD_DI`, `SD_DO`, `SC_SCK` and `SD_SS`) is for the SD card slot only.

All the pins starting `LCD_` are the 8-bit parallel ("8080" style) interface for controlling the TFT screen.